# MySQL Delete last 1300 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I am cleaning up someones contact form Mysql database and the last 1300+ rows were spam. Is there a way with `DELETE FROM my_table_name` to specify a sequence of rows to delete? There is no time stamp or I would use that.

Comment: Does each row have an identifier?

Comment: Is there an `auto_increment` column?

Comment: @SimeonVisser no his whole site was done horribly. It was done in tables instead of divs like 10 years ago

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski no, its a horrible site and database.

Comment: I'm still fairly new at using this site, don't get why people vote down questions, I searched the site before I wrote it. All I could find is answers with conditions. Everyone had to learn at some point.

Comment: The downvote was _probably_ because certain key details were missing -  you said your table didn't have a timestamp, but you didn't supply information about what columns it _does_ have, which is very pertinent to how a deletion could be crafted.  Further, you didn't give much evidence that you had researched the [MySQL `DELETE` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) and the `ORDER BY,LIMIT` options it offers.  The more you volunteer rather than have to have it dragged out in comments, the more likely to get upvotes.

Comment: We call a downvote with no associated explaining comment a "drive-by downvote".

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski lol... on the "drive-by downvote phrase"... I did search the questions here and on google, but everything I found was about having certain conditions with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by the main key and limit

```
DELETE FROM my_table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1300
```

Comment: Nice, much better than mine

Comment: Just tried it, it gave me this error `Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near "ORDER": syntax error)`

Comment: Is the field you used for `id` a valid field? `id` was an example field presuming there is some field you have that is incremental that can sort the rows, for example auto_increment or a date field. If you don't have such a field, we can dynamically assign row numbers to the fields and sort by the numbers. A bit more work.

Comment: Ya I'm idiot, just realized that, I was coming back hoping to edit my comment to Thank you before you saw it :)

Answer (score 3):

If there is an `id` and assuming it is a primary auto-incrementing key of the table

```
DELETE FROM my_table_name WHERE id > 1234
```

where `1234` is the first ID of the spam entries.